# ObservableCollection<T> exposed as IEnumerable<T> still treated as former?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a view model that exposes a `ObservableCollection<TInheritor>` collection as `IEnumerable<TBaseInterface>` (for the covariance). If I bind that property to the `ItemsSource` property on a ListBox, is that ListBox still smart enough to use my source as an `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: Yes.............. Have you tried it before askin here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it will do that, there shouldn't be any problems using an ObservableCollection like this. Here is an example: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e06010/observablecollection-in-wpf/

Comment: The answer is "yes", but your link doesn't have an example of what I was looking for.